# Javascript random color generator, but with favouritism to strong colors

Tags: javascript, colors

I am currently using the following to generate a random hex color in javascript:

```
function getColor(){
     return '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
}
```

Every time one of these colors is generated they will be pushed into an array:

```
var colors = new Array();
```

I want the getColor function to always pick from 'whole' colors first.  Such as 'Red' (#FF0000) and 'Yellow' (#FFFF00) and only after confirming that all these 'whole' colors are already taken by checking against the colors array, should it then proceed to offer more obscure/mixed colors such as 'GreenYellow' (#ADFF2F) etc.

So essentially the function should eventually populate the colors array with every hex based color there is, starting with the strongest of colors (what I am describing as 'whole' colors) then moving on to the weaker 'mixed' colors, finally finishing on black  as it will be considered the least desirable of all.

Unfortunately I really have no idea where to begin other than to provide a complete array of colors in the exact order I want and then to iterate through them.

This seems rather like using a sledgehammer to a crack a nut.  Any other more elegant solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Please note:** I understand that the terminology I've used here isn't really correct but hopefully people will understand what I mean by 'whole' colors. I really can't think of any better way to articulate it.

**EDIT:** It may help to understand a bit about the reason for needing this.  The colors will be used to visually identify items beginning to the same group as a user groups them together themselves.  The majority of the time there will only be several groups, perhaps up to an average of 20-30.  Therefore it makes sense to use strong colors that are clear to see and differentiate from one another first before moving onto colors which may look more similar.

Comment: I think you need a better description of exactly how this array should be populated and in what order. It's really not clear from your description. Try writing it out as a series of steps or a flow chart. And what, *exactly* do you mean by random in this context? Because it seems like what you are describing (starting with "whole" colors and ending with black) isn't exactly random. So is it only partially random? Or not really random at all?

Comment: And do you really mean `#FF60000`, because to me "*whole red*" would be `#FF0000`

Comment: Indeed, I've found it very hard to articulate.  My apologies. Partially random would be the best way to describe my needs.  Whole colors, followed by all other colors, followed finally by black.

Comment: @MattBurland - Sorry that was a type-o.

Comment: "Whole color" as in primary color? For blending colors the RGB color space won't work well. Try using the [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating colors that appear different is more about human perception than math.  Some color pairs the same distance apart in RGB values look more similar than others.

Bu even so, I don't think you want to figure this out in RGB.  Instead, try generating your colors in HSL or HSV: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

This allows to control hue, saturation and brightness, which is closer to the attributes humans perceive about color.  You could then generate colors by varying hue with other attributes constant.

```
// assume hue is in degrees here
// think of hue like a circle with each angle a different color.
red     = hsv(0,   1, 1);
green   = hsv(120, 1, 1);
blue    = hsv(240, 1, 1);
```

You could then start subdividing the hue space tighter.

```
yellow  = hsv(60,  1, 1);
cyan    = hsv(180, 1, 1);
magenta = hsv(300, 1, 1);
```

Once the hues get to close to close together, drop the saturation or the brightness and do it again.

```
// run through all hues again but with half the value
darkRed = hsv(0, 1, 0.5);

// run through all hues again but with half the saturation
lightRed = hsv(0, 0.5, 1);

// run through all hues again but with half the value and half the saturation
desatRad = hsv(0, 0.5, 0.5);
```

Then you could even subdivide the saturation/value space to 0.25 and 0.75.  What I've described is a strategy for a recursive algorithm that generates colors an unique as possible, returning the boldest/brightest ones first.  And it's also *not random* because it doesn't need to be.

All you need is a hsv/hsl to hex library in javascript, which i'm sure there is one somewhere, and some math.

Comment: This is absolutely spot on and definitely the correct approach to take. I cant believe I didn't think of switching to HSV in the first place. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier if you reduce your color pattle to 256 or less colors, if that quantity of color would be sufficient, since would be very hard to a human eye to differentiate #0000FF and #0000FE.

I'm not sure if I understood you need non repeated colors on that array, if so you will need to check against the previous values in order to get unique colors.